# SIR model (3 differential equations)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, biology

> The SIR model for epidemics is Susceptible (not yet infected) -> Infected (have disease and are infectious) -> Recovered (recovered from the disease)
> and is governed by the system of 3 differential equations
>
> $$\begin{split}\frac {dS}{dt}&=-\frac{\beta IS}{N}\\ 
> \frac{dR}{dt}&=\gamma I\\ 
> \frac{dI}{dt}&=\frac{\beta IS}{N}-\gamma I\end{split}$$
>
> Determine the final epidemic size, i.e. the total number of people infected
> when $S(0)=N$ and there is an infinitesimal initial infection. Express
> the fraction infected ($\frac{R(\infty)}{N}$) as a function of $R_0$. Note: it will be an implicit function.

$\beta, \gamma$ are parameters and can be considered constants. It has been a while since I took differential equations - how would one solve for $R(\infty)$? We seek $R(\infty)$ not $I(\infty)$ here because $R$ tells you everyone who has recovered and hence went through the disease phase, but $I$ would just be the current infected.

Comment: The sum $S+I+R$ stays constant over time... If you start with $S(0) = N$, you need to set $I(0) = R(0) = 0$ and, in parcitular, you will never get any infected or recovered.

Comment: "Infinitessimal initial infection" probably means that you should use $S(0) = N - \varepsilon$ and $I(0) = \varepsilon$ for arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: I think I was incorrect in saying that $N$ is the population size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $S'+I'+R' = 0$, so the equations are linearly dependent, i.e. we have more equations than we need. We limit our study to just the $S'$ and $R'$ equations, eliminating $I$ algbebraically to get

$$S'(t) = -\frac{R_0R'(t)}{N}S(t)$$

where $R_0 = \beta/\gamma$, which has solution

$$ S(t) = S(0)\exp\left(-\frac{R_0(R(t)-R(0))}{N}\right) $$

Taking the limit as $t\to\infty$, while noting that $I\to 0$ and so $S\to N-R$, we get

$$ N - R(\infty) = S(0)\exp\left(-\frac{R_0(R(\infty)-R(0))}{N}\right) $$

Apply the initial conditions $S(0) = N - \varepsilon$ and $R(0) = 0$. Since $\varepsilon$ can be arbitrarily small, we can take the limit as $\varepsilon\to 0$ so it vanishes from the solution

$$N - R(\infty) = N\exp\left(-\frac{R_0R(\infty)}{N}\right)$$

Let's clean it up by naming the quantity of interest $\rho = R(\infty)/N$, and rearranging the equation a bit to get

$$\rho = 1 - \exp(-R_0\rho)$$

Note that this is not explicit, as expected.

Comment: incredible, thanks so much!

Comment: Now do $R_0(ρ-1)e^{R_0(ρ-1)}=-R_0e^{-R_0}$ to get $R_0(ρ-1)=W_{k}(-R_0e^{-R_0})$, $k=0,-1$. One branch of the Lambert-W function obviously gives $W_k(-R_0e^{-R_0})=-R_0$, thus $ρ=0$, so one needs the second real branch of the Lambert-W function for the non-trivial result.

Comment: Nice answer!  I’m looking for a textbook on the mathematical modeling of infectious disease that would include an explanation like this, not just for SIR, but also for other models including Galton-Watson, SEIR, Reed-Frost, and next generation transition matrices where $R_0$ is the dominant eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way of doing it:

Solve the system of ODEs. Take the limit as $t \rightarrow \infty$ of the function you've solved for, $R(t)$. Write this in terms of $R_0$ alone and divide out by $N$.